# Why do highland/alpine plants require a drop in night temperatures to thrive?

Tags: botany, metabolism, plant-physiology, energy-metabolism

There are mountain plants which require a drop in nightly temperature (many Nepenthes, Heliamphora and orchids for example). A non-specialist explanation is that the plants die of "starvation" if you do not provide cold nights, that During warm nights they metabolize their stored energy reserves much faster than they're adapted to do in natural environments, leading to overexpenditure and eventual death.

Is that plausible and if so can it be expressed in scientific terms?

Would extending the photo period be a simple way of counteracting this?

Comment: What research have you conducted to try to find an answer? As you have credit from another SE community you will be aware that this is requirement for posts.

Comment: There's a possibility this might fit on [gardening.se] if it doesn't work here. Nonetheless, interesting question, perhaps show your attempt to answer  - anything you found on the subject and where it lead you.

Comment: There's this paper (https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.0914299107) that finds starch accumulation during the daytime is basically linear and more importantly, the plant then proceeds to use up those stores until dawn when they're basically depleted. I had already assumed that because it makes sense for an equilibrium state to evolve. This seems to support the logic behind the starvation hypothesis, I haven't found anything looking at the starch degradation in alpine plants however. I really want to know if there are metabolic processes that can't happen at all without a temperature drop.

Comment: At first, I also thought that it might be an equilibrium problem for metabolites and revcheckd the Michaelis-Menten equation.

However, the metabolic reaction stops (or appears to stop) because
 -All enzymes are lost or inactivated.
 -All substrates are lost.
 -The enzymatic reaction reaches an equilibrium
All of the substrates are lost.

If the temperature is around 10°C, the enzymes are not completely deactivated. Nor is the enzymatic reaction in equilibrium, since the starch will continue to be broken down until dawn.
So I thought there is not enough CO2 in the material.

Answer (score 3):

That's an interesting explanation.

I don't know of a definitive paper, so I write here only a guess.

Perhaps in alpine plants that are stressed by high temperatures at night, abscisic acid is produced and the stomata close, preventing CO2 uptake and photosynthesis.

CO2, the material for photosynthesis, is taken up by the leaves by opening the stomata at night.
Abscisic acid, a plant hormone that closes these stomata, appears to be synthesized in response well to stress responses.
https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpls.2016.00571/full

In common plants, it seems to be synthesized in response to dryness, high salt concentrations, and low temperatures, but alpine plants may have a mechanism to recognize high temperatures at night as stress.

About abscisic acid, it is still under research, especially its receptors and signals.